# Python: MergeSort data input

Tags: python, algorithm, input

I want to make an MergeSort algorithm, and i want to get my data from external file like an txt, when i import my files i get some strange results [9. 9. 9. 9.] my input data is [12, 44, 11, 9] i think it is because of the numpy import but i'm not sure.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.genfromtxt("data/123.txt", delimiter=',')

def mergeSort(alist):
    print("Splitting ",alist)
    if len(alist)>1:
        mid = len(alist)//2
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:]

        mergeSort(lefthalf)
        mergeSort(righthalf)

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i < len(lefthalf):
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j < len(righthalf):
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
    print("Merging ",alist)

alist = x
mergeSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can debug and note that merging [11] and [9] gives [9,9].

It is due to the fact that  your "list" is really numpy array, and slicing here

```
    lefthalf = alist[:mid]
    righthalf = alist[mid:]
```

creates  a view (reference) onto some position of parent object, not new instance of array. That is why `alist[k]=righthalf[j]` operation overwrites `11` value in `lefthalf`

[All arrays generated by basic slicing are always views of the original array.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

The simplest way to get around is casting of ndarray to standard list:

```
x = list(np.genfromtxt("e:/123.txt", delimiter=','))
```

but more reliable approach is rewriting code with creation of new arrays.

Answer (score 0):

When you overwrite lefthalf or righthalf, you are also overwriting alist.
You can avoid this by using copy() function as below.

```
lefthalf = alist[:mid].copy()
righthalf = alist[mid:].copy()
```